# Deleting Blank Rows then adding a row before a column value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new here and have been racking my brain for about a week to try and figure this out.  I have also searched everywhere and every example I try to fix my issue doesn't work.  So, I apologize if this is somewhere on here but couldn't find it.

My delema, I have a computer generated spreadsheet that creates over 2000 lines in Excel.  Half are empty blank rows.  My goal is to delete all of the empty rows then insert a rows before, if column "n" has a value of Y or N.

I have the delete the blank rows figured out but am struggling on adding the rows based on the value.  Any help would be appreciated.

---

```
Sub DeleteBlankRows()
  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim WorkRng As Range

  On Error Resume Next
  xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"

  Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
  Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)

  xRows = WorkRng.Rows.Count
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  For i = xRows To 1 Step -1
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(WorkRng.Rows(i)) = 0 Then
      WorkRng.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp
    End If
  Next

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub InsertRow()
  If ActiveCell = "y" Then
    Selection.EntireRow.Insert
    If ActiveCell = "n" Then
      Selection.EntireRow.Insert
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: 1st thing: In you `Sub InsertRow()` you put `If ActiveCell = "n" Then` inside y.

Comment: You forgot to add `on error goto 0` at the end of your code too

Answer (score 0):

Combine the logic of your first routine with the second (code not tested)

```
Sub DeleteBlankRows()

  Const COLUMN_TO_CHECK_FOR_Y_N = 10&

  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim WorkRng As Range

  On Error Resume Next
  xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"

  Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
  Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)

  xRows = WorkRng.Rows.Count
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  ' Delete Rows
  For i = xRows To 1 Step -1
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(WorkRng.Rows(i)) = 0 Then
      WorkRng.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp
    End If
  Next

  ' Add Rows
  For i = xRows To 1 Step -1
    If WorkRng.Cells(i, COLUMN_TO_CHECK_FOR_Y_N) = "N" Then
      WorkRng.Rows(i).Insert
    End If
  Next

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Note that you should stay away from Selection and ActiveCell. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10717999/772086).

Comment: This removes the empty rows but not adding the rows

Comment: You will probably need to update the constant COLUMN_TO_CHECK_FOR_Y_N from 10 to whatever column number your Y/N column is in. So, if your Y/N column is in column C, then the column number is 3. As always, step through the code if something doesn't work quite right. Good Luck!